# git clone replicates submodules, but they are not repos anymore

Tags: git

I have a project I want to clone:

`$ git clone repo1 repo2`

Everything copies over.  Then I initiate submodules:

`$ git submodule update --init --recursive`

It downloads and populates the folders for all the submodules.  I move into a directory of a submodule, and it's not a proper repo anymore.

I look closely at the submodule files and the `.git` folder has instead been turned into a file. This means I can't do development work on the submodules in the newly cloned project.

How do I get the clone to replicate the submodules, as git repos themselves, per the original project?

EDIT: May this have something to do with cloning from a relative path on the same machine?  Perhaps an absolute path changes the manner of the clone?

This thread is exactly the same issue I'm having, but I just don't see the proposed solution as being the ideal answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459532/revert-to-pre-git-v1-7-8-git-submodule-behavior-with-submodule-filesystem-locati

Answer (score 0):

I've learned initiated submodules are headless.  Fix:

`$ git submodule foreach git checkout master`